# DialogFragment with ListView height is different on API 25 as in previous versions.

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-layout-weight

As the title says I want to know why my ListView grows in height in my DialogFragment on API level 25 even if there are not that much items in it?
I already had a look at similar questions but they all used the same layout componentes -> LinearLayout and a layout_weight of "1" of ListView.

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:drawableLeft="?attr/title_clipboard"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Records"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvData"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvNoEntries"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="25dp"
    android:text="@string/no_entries_for_day"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvManual"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/clipboard_info"
    android:textSize="8sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llReminder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Reminder" />


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spReminder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:entries="@array/clipboard_reminder_strings"
        android:prompt="@string/time_popup_trip_type" />
</LinearLayout>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btClose"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:text="@string/bt_Close" />
```

This is how I want it to be (API 23 and all before 25):
[image]

This is how it looks on API 25:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvData"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

with

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvData"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: This is wrong since it would move my control below out of sight when ListView becomes to big!